# An unknown error has occurred with graph Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have an element on my website which shows facebook posts from a page and the amount of views/likes/comments. This stopped working all of a sudden and I have no idea why.

If I make the request with the graph api tester tool I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1,
      "fbtrace_id": "CIHVxFhXIv/"
   }
}
```

This is the request link I use with file_get_contents:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/idofmypage/posts?fields=comments,full_picture,likes,message,picture,story,permalink_url,updated_time,from,insights.metric(post_impressions)&access_token=myaccesstoken
```

Did something change again with permissions or maybe a field is deprecated?

Comment: Can reproduce; seems to work once `likes` is removed from the field list though. Might have to do with the current changes regarding privacy.

Comment: @CBroe Yes that makes it work again. I hope Facebook announces what to do soon because now all likes are at 0.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this fb new](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/) the Pages API and others have changed, and now you can only access the data if it's a page of your own.

> Pages API: Until today, any app could use the Pages API to read posts or comments from any Page. This let developers create tools for Page owners to help them do things like schedule posts and reply to comments or messages. But it also let apps access more data than necessary. We want to make sure Page information is only available to apps providing useful services to our community. So starting today, all future access to the Pages API will need to be approved by Facebook.

Today I've started a project wich, in the begging, I need to recollect data and that's what I've found about it..

Comment: Thanks for the information. Still it's weird that I can read the amount of comments and views, but not likes.

Comment: Sorry @twan I didn't see the notification. Maybe you can still do it because you own the page.. don't you?

Comment: Yes I own it, but I'm not sure how to get the likes, the old way is definately not working anymore.